# How to use asp:Repeater tag and then use data-binding expressions without declare Microsoft SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

How to use **asp:Repeater** tag and then use data-binding expressions without declare Microsoft SQL Server database?

Because I ask question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976082/how-to-for-loop-asplabel-or-aspplaceholder-tag-with-select-aspcheckbox-any-ch) but I learn **asp:Repeater** tag article have to declare Microsoft SQL Server database in DataBind article.

I ask question to solve "How to use **asp:Repeater** tag and then use data-binding expressions without declare Microsoft SQL Server database."

Comment: You can bind Repeater controller to any type of collection. And that collection can be populated by any mean. https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=322

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks you to useful information , I have recovery source at [original link](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=322) to new source code at [new link](https://github.com/doanga2007/GenericRepeater).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news :** I have answer to use asp:Repeater tag and then use data-binding expressions without declare Microsoft SQL Server database.

My full source code.

https://github.com/doanga2007/CheckLoopQR

1. Default.aspx (HTML Code)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckLoopQR.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){

    $("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>QR Code Generator</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Please Input Data</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQRCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Generate" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Display Text" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" /><br /><br />

            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"/><asp:Label id="checkTextAll" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />

            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Border="1"
            BorderColor="LightGray" Font-Size="Large"></asp:CheckBoxList>  

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Default.aspx.cs (C# Code)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using ZXing.Common;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace CheckLoopQR
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.checkTextAll.Text = " Check All";
        }
        protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = txtQRCode.Text;
            long num = Convert.ToInt64(code);

            int i;

            for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                num += i;
                CheckBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(" " + num));
            }
        }
        protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }

            string[] texture = { "Selected Item Text1 : ", "Selected Item Text2 : ", "Selected Item Text3 : " };
            int a = 0;

            foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBox1.Items)
            {
                if (listItem.Selected)
                {
                    a++;

                    string code = listItem.Text;

                    CheckBox1.Visible = false;
                    checkAll.Visible = false;
                    checkTextAll.Visible = false;

                    QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions();

                    options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                    {
                        DisableECI = true,
                        CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
                        Width = 150,
                        Height = 150,
                        Margin = 0,
                    };

                    var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
                    barcodeWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                    barcodeWriter.Options = options;

                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    imgBarCode.Height = 150;
                    imgBarCode.Width = 150;

                    Label lblvalues = new Label();
                    lblvalues.Text += texture[a-1] + listItem.Text;
                    lblvalues.Font.Size = FontUnit.Large;
                    Label lblvalues2 = new Label();
                    lblvalues2.Text += texture[a-1] + listItem.Text;
                    lblvalues2.Font.Size = FontUnit.Large;
                    Label lblvalues3 = new Label();
                    lblvalues3.Text += texture[a-1] + listItem.Text;
                    lblvalues3.Font.Size = FontUnit.Large;

                    using (Bitmap bitMap = barcodeWriter.Write(code))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                            imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                        }
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblvalues);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblvalues2);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblvalues3);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something else 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```